# Selenium I want to get a specific property of this Element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I want to get the value of this aria-checked = ‘true’ as shown in the screenshot below. I am able to get this value easily by using below code:

```
WebElement searchTextBox= driver.findElement(By.className(“ui-igcheckbox-container”));
// retrieving html attribute value using getAttribute() method
String typeValue=searchTextBox.getAttribute(“aria-checked”);
System.out.println("Value of type attribute: "+typeValue);
```

But the problem here is I want to get this value Dynamically above code only returns only first value of the table row. Can anyone help me how to get this value dynamically?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `get this value Dynamically` ?

Comment: I meant as you can see there are three rows in this table currently. I want to get the value of each row separatly. At this point my code only returns first value of the table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there are multiple elements (checkboxes) matching this locator you may get all them into a list and get each element attribute iterating over that list

```
List<WebElement> searchTextBoxes= driver.findElements(By.className(“ui-igcheckbox-container”));
for(WebElement searchTextBox : searchTextBoxes){
    String typeValue=searchTextBox.getAttribute(“aria-checked”);
    System.out.println("Value of type attribute: "+typeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if all 3 have this class

```
ui-igcheckbox-container
```

but since they are check box they will definitely have :

```
span[role='checkbox']
```

you can use `findElements` like this :-

```
List<WebElement> searchTextBoxes= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(“span[role='checkbox']”));
for(WebElement searchTextBox : searchTextBoxes){
    String typeValue = searchTextBox.getAttribute(“aria-checked”);
    System.out.println("Value of type attribute: "+typeValue);
}
```